# I'm having a socket IO connection issue

Tags: node.js, sockets, reactjs, express

I'm working in react js and using sockets and express to set up a multiplayer game

I'm getting this error:

polling-xhr.js:264 
GET https://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LqjOuC2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

I've google this error like 5 times and adjusted my imports with app, socket, express and http,

Server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
http.listen(port, ()=> {console.log("+++Express Server with Socket 
Running!!!")})
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
....
....
```

front-end

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Test from "./Test"
import io from "socket.io-client"
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'

//  ***********************************
//  Handles user creation and contains routes to game
//  ***********************************

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.home = this.home.bind(this)
  this.socket = io.connect("https://localhost:3000")
}
....
....
```

My package.json has a proxy set up at: "https://localhost:3000/"

Anyone have an idea how to fix the connection error, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: i found the error, can't use https on io.connect